# Referencing Parent Arraylist from Within Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, parent-child, parent, backtrace

So I was wondering if it was possible in Java to trace back up an Array List? Meaning, if I have something like:

```
Section aSection = new Section();
aMainSection.get(0).aChildSection.add(aSection);
```

Where 'aMainSection' and 'aChildSection' are both Array Lists of type section, can I trace back up from 'aChildSection' to get the values stored in it's parent section 'aMainSection'? Or do I have to create some sort of method within the section class that will do this? Thanks for any help that is offered.

Comment: if `aMainSection` is `ArrayList` of `Section` Objects, `aMainSection.get(0)` will give `Section` Object. How could you use `aMainSection.get(0).aChildSection` ?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad That really depends on the access level of the `aChildSection` field and where the code is being executed - if it's public, it can be accessed using that syntax in any object. If it's private, but we're calling that code in another instance of the Section class, then it can also be accessed using that syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot find all the references to an object from the object itself.  You can instead record a "parent" Object in each of the children.

Instead of exposing the raw collections you may way to have custom classes for them.

```
class ChildSection {
    private final Section parent;
    private final List<Section> sections = new ArraysList<Section>();

    public void add(Section section) {
        sections.add(section);
        section.setParent(parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I'll try implementing that in my code.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't track upwards with ArrayLists, you will have to add parent references in each Section object.